# Does the graph embedding algorithms works for other languages than English?

Tags: neo4j

In my graph, both the relationship names and property names are in Chinese. Does this affect the quality of the embedding models when using the models? I am wondering how those relationships and properties are transformed into features. The below is one example of node property:

```
{
  "_出生地": "日本兵库县",
  "_国籍": "日本",
  "_义项": "1",
  "_节点ID": "55bac8328e7b30ec288ae7cd2c958070",
  "_中文名": "明神智和",
  "_生日": "1978-1-24",
  "_入库日期": "2020-04-17",
  "_名称": "MJ",
  "_运动项目": "足球",
  "_重要事件": "代表日本队参加2002世界杯",
  "_体重": "66公斤",
  "_频道": "体育",
  "_运动队": "长野伙伴足球俱乐部（17）",
  "_外文名": "Tomokazu Myojin",
  "_身高": "173厘米",
  "_类型": "运动员"
}
```

Comment: In Neo4j, and probably most graph embedding algorithms, you can only input node and relationship properties that are either integer or float. So it doesn't really matter what language you have, because you can't input a string into a graph embedding algorithm anyway

Comment: I see. I need extra code to encode the strings.

Comment: Yes, perhaps something like a one-hot-encoding

Comment: @TomažBratanič, for string relationship name, I don't need to do any extra work. Right? The algorithm will automatically convert to integer or float.